# tableadaptor - delete rows

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012

I have a dataset created in visual studio designer. It has a tableadaptor for charges.

One of the columns in the charges table is 'booking'. This column is NOT a primary key.

I want to delete all rows where the value of 'booking' is 27.

I added a query to the chargesTableAdaptor called DeleteByBooking. It's code:

```
DELETE FROM charges
WHERE        (chargesid = @Original_chargesid)
```

In my code I then run:

```
this.chargesTableAdapter.DeleteBookingCharges(27);
this.chargesBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.chargesTableAdapter.Update(this.quick_quoteDataSet.charges);
```

Despite the code building fine, and the app running ok, no rows get deleted from the database!

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2):

> I added a query to the chargesTableAdaptor called DeleteByBooking

If you add a query manually, you have to call this method on your TableAdapter instance manually:

```
chargesTableAdapter.DeleteByBooking(27);
```

If you want to use the `Update` functionality on your (strongly typed) DataSet,DataTable or DataRow, you have to provide the `DeleteCommand` of the `TableAdapter`.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> **TableAdapter Update Method**
>
> TableAdapters use data commands to read to and write from the
> database. The TableAdapter's initial Fill (main) query is used as the
> basis for creating the schema of the associated data table, as well as
> the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and **DeleteCommand** commands
> associated with the **TableAdapter.Update** method. This means that
> calling a TableAdapter's Update method executes the statements created
> when the TableAdapter was originally configured, **and not one of the
> additional queries added** with the TableAdapter Query Configuration
> Wizard.

Note that the commands are created automatically if you select one table in the TableAdapter configuration wizard. If you join multiple tables you have to create the Update,Insert and DeleteCommand manually.

Comment: Sorry, my original post contained an error. My delete query IS called DeleteBookingCharges So the first line of my code above is the same as you suggest in your answser. It's not doing anything when it gets to that line?! Thanks

Comment: @MatthewWinter: Sorry I don't quite follow. Have you provided a delete-command in your TableAdapter? Then you could delete the row e.g. by calling `chargeRow.Delete();` followed by `this.chargesTableAdapter.Update(this.quick_quoteDataSet.charges);`. If you want to delete it without using `Update` you have to provide and  manual query that you can call with the required parameters like `chargesid`. Btw, the `EndEdit` is not necessary, try to omit it, i don't know what consequence it has.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a dataGrid as control you can try this without SQL queries, equally you can adapt this code just editing the dataset line.

```
DataSet.yourRow iAmARow;
try
{

   iAMARow = 
   this.yourDataSet.yourTable.FindByBooking(nameOfTheColumn);

   if (iAmARow != null)
   {
       iAmARow.Delete();
       this.yourTableAdapter.Update(this.yourDataSet);
       this.yourDataSet.yourTable.AcceptChanges();

   }

}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   ex.StackTrace.ToString();
}
```

I hope that it can help you.
;)